# Disable strict sql mode for a inline query in mysql

Tags: mysql, configuration

Can some how i could Disable strict sql mode for a stored procedure or inline query in mysql?
I just wanted to either disable for single sp/query  or a single database.
What i have tried is

```
set sql_mode='' ;INSERT INTO system_log(appname, action, level, thread_id, context,
                        context_id,market_id, message,transaction_id,primary_msisdn,primary_issuer
                        ,secondary_msisdn,secondary_issuer, merchant_id,acquirer_id)
                        VALUES(
                          @appname, @action,@level, @thread_id, @context 
                          , @context_id 
                          ,@market_id 
                          ,CASE WHEN @message = 'NULL' THEN NULL ELSE @message END
                          ,@transaction_id     
                          ,@primary_msisdn 
                          ,@primary_issuer                          
                          ,@secondary_msisdn,@secondary_issuer, @merchant_id,@acquirer_id

                          );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set the session version of the sql_mode server system variable:

```
SET SESSION sql_mode = ''; --no mode set
```

After that you can restore sql_mode by setting it to the appropriate value.

However, I would rather consider rewriting the stored procedure so that you do not have to change the sql mode.

Comment: Actually it was an inline script of log4net adonet appender for inserting the data. what i have done is simply appendend the query with 
set sql_mode='' ;INSERT INTO system_log(appname, action, level, thread_id, context.... and it seems working fine

Comment: What is the difference between SET SESSION sql_mode = ''; and SET  sql_mode = '';

Comment: Nothing, they afe the same. However, set it back to what it was after the query.

Comment: If it is a separate database then please let me know that even changing it on session will effect other sessions with different db or not.